# "absolute position" view inside scrollview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, css-position

I don't know if this is possible but maybe someone can help me:
My scrollview size is 400*400px and what I want is a column/view inside on the left of the scrollview (40px wide) that always stays visible when the user scrolls horizontally, but moves together with the view when the user scrolls vertically.

[here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrhI5.png)

So the red part should always be visible when there's horizontal scrolling and the yellow part becomes visible on vertical scrolling. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Set yourself as the delegate of the scrollview and implement `-scrollViewDidScroll:`. In this method, check the `contentOffset` of the scrollView and adjust the position of your "absolutely-positioned" view accordingly.

Note that this method is called for every single frame of the scroll, so try not to do anything particularly expensive here. It may be called 60 times a second.